# Preventing IndexOutOfRangeException on arrays

Tags: c#

I looking for a way to prevent IndexOutOfRangeException when I try to access a specific array index.

I have a generic code that some times has values at `array[index]`, and other times there is not.

so, before trying to get its value I have tried these checks:

```
if(array[index] != null) {
    ... Do Stuff
}
```

Also tried:

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(array[index])) {
    ... Do Stuff
}
```

They all trows an IndexOutOfRangeException

How could I perform this check?

Comment: Why is your code attempting to access memory outside the bounds of the array in the first place? Don't try and catch an error.. remove the error.

Comment: What is the type of `array`?

Comment: Just fixed. My code need some bug fixes. This is one of them. I was just curious why I was not able to check for a null index. Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Very simple:

```
if (index < array.Length)
```

Comment: While this is correct.. I feel like it should be within the loop initializer.. instead of being checked from within (I'm assuming it's a loop).

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I have to fix my code to prevent this. I was just curious why cheking for null was not working

Comment: @GuilhermeLongo: `Array[999]` _isn't_ `null`; rather, it doesn't exist at all.  The exception when you get the value in the first place, before the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use try... catch to suppress the error. Brute?

```
try
{
   var x = array[index];
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
}
```

And better

```
if(array.Length > index)
   var x = array[index];
```